# Posting from React to Flask: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: json, python-2.7, reactjs, http, flask

Before I get linked to another thread, I've checked the other answers on this forum about this problem.  My JSON is formatted correctly and the JSON doesn't contain HMTL. I know 'Key' is in single quotes but double quotes doesn't fix the problem. The request is going to local host.

Here's the POST from the react file:

```
fetch(URL + '/api/' + this.props.choice, {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body:JSON.stringify({'Key': this.state.value})
              })
```

Here's the GET from the Flask file:

```
@app.route('/api/Junk', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def junk():
        junk_request = request.get_json(force = True)
        print junk_request
        junk_date_var = junk_request["Key"]
```

The error message from Chrome Debugger:

```
fetch uncaught (in promise) syntaxerror: unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Output from the terminal:

```
{u'Key': u'Select'}
```

u just means it's a unicode character. What's also strange is that this EXACT code was working a few days ago. This makes me think that some permission is off or something is going wrong with Node.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a get request made to '/api/Junk' with no JSON code.  Milliseconds later, a second post request was made to '/api/Junk' with valid JSON.

So, python would try to decode nothing when it expected JSON, fail, then decode and print the valid JSON that came in milliseconds later.